# ResponsiveSlides.js plugin not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I use Zurbs Foundation framework to develop my sites but do not like their built in orbit slider so have opted to use another responsive slider which I really like. The slider works perfectly in every browser I have tested it in apart from IE.

The plugin I use is http://responsiveslides.com/. The plugin works in IE on their site but not mine but I am using the exact same code so cannot understand why it does not work.

Does anyone know why it is working on the site above but not mine, the website I am using this slider on is http://www.viscari.co.uk/client.

If you require any more information from me please let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help given.

Comment: Remove any `console` uses you might have. They won't work in IE without the dev tools open.

Comment: Please specifiy the IE version(s) you're having problems with. There are significant differences between the various versions of IE.

Comment: I have tested this in IE 9 & 10 so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) to make IE support HTML5!

Comment: This slider doesn't use any HTML5 elements. Cheers